# data.frame to timeseries object

Tags: r, type-conversion, dataframe, time-series

I got a data frame object that looks the following way:

```
Date        dax_data.csv    nikkei_data.csv spx_data.csv
2013-03-15  NA              NA              1560.70
2013-03-14  NA              NA              1563.23
2013-03-13  NA              NA              1554.52
2013-03-12  NA              NA              1552.48
2013-03-11  NA              NA              1556.22
2013-03-08  8020.36         12283.62        1551.18

...

1984-01-04  4533.21         9927.00         900.42
1984-01-05  NA              9947.00         NA
1984-01-06  NA              9961.00         NA
```

I want to do the following steps:

- Reduce the data frame to only cover the date range where all the datasets have values. In this example from `1984-01-04` to `2013-03-08` (cant be hardcoded, needs to be dynamical and all the NAs in between need to be kept).
- The frequency of the data needs to be weekly, the first value should be the oldest value in the dataframe. I.e. in this example `1984-01-04`.
- The data frame object needs to be converted to a timeSeries object.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You don't explain how your data will be reduced to weekly frequency. I mean do you take any value from the week? or do you take the mean of values?...

Here an option using `xts` package , convenient for this manipulations specially for financial time series.

```
library(xts)
dat.ts <- xts(dat[,-1],as.POSIXct(dat$Date))
dat.ts[endpoints(dat.ts,'weeks')]

           dax_data.csv nikkei_data.csv spx_data.csv
1984-01-06           NA            9961           NA
2013-03-11           NA              NA      1556.22
2013-03-15           NA              NA      1560.70
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I was going to take any value from the week, if no one suggests anything else, I was going to do: t+5

Comment: Basically from the first date, always adding 5 days.

Your script didnt work I think. The output is not trimmed and still has daily values.

Comment: @Spurious my output is weekly one. What do you get when you test it in you real data? and for adding five days , you need just to add 5 to `endpoints` result. `dat.ts[endpoints(dat.ts,'weeks')+5]`

Comment: when I write your code to a csv, I still got the same data as before. Neither weekly data nor trimmed.
Is tehre anything else, you need me to post to get a better indication?

Comment: maybe you should assign the values to `dat.ts <- dat.ts[endpoints(dat.ts,'weeks')]`...

Comment: I am not sure what you mean? I get an output, just not a modified one.

Comment: try to chnage the last line in my answer by this : `dat.ts <- dat.ts[endpoints(dat.ts,'weeks')]`..

Comment: It works now! Thank you. But I still dont have the values trimmed.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26290/discussion-between-agstudy-and-spurious)

Answer (score 1):

We read in the data using `read.zoo` and trim all NA rows at the beginning and end using `na.trim`.   (Note that `read.zoo` can also "read" data frames and files.)

Then we aggregate all rows having the same value for `nextfri` (which is defined in the [zoo Quick Reference vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/vignettes/zoo-quickref.pdf)).  `nextfri` takes a Date vector and for each component returns the next Friday (or the same Date if its already Friday).  The actual aggregation function is `tail1` (the last row in each week) but we could have substituted any other reasonable aggregation function such as `mean`.  (See `?aggregate.zoo`).

Lastly we convert the `"zoo"` time series to a `"timeSeries"` time series.  Depending on what you intend to do next you might not need this last step.

```
Lines <- "
Date        dax_data.csv    nikkei_data.csv spx_data.csv
2013-03-15  NA              NA              1560.70
2013-03-14  NA              NA              1563.23
2013-03-13  NA              NA              1554.52
2013-03-12  NA              NA              1552.48
2013-03-11  NA              NA              1556.22
2013-03-08  8020.36         12283.62        1551.18
1984-01-04  4533.21         9927.00         900.42
1984-01-05  NA              9947.00         NA
1984-01-06  NA              9961.00         NA
"

library(zoo)

z.raw <- read.zoo(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
z <- na.trim(z, is.na = "all")

nextfri <- function(x) 7 * ceiling(as.numeric(x-5+4) / 7) + as.Date(5-4)
tail1 <- function(x) tail(x, 1)
z.wk <- aggregate(z, nextfri, tail1)

library(timeSeries)
as.timeSeries(z.wk)
```